# Update not all Bootstrap grid breakpoints

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-grid

I have 2 questions:
1. What the *$container-max-width* Bootstrap variable is used for?
2. How should I override the variables if I need the following resolutions?

```
 sm: 0px -> 768px - tablet portrait
 md: 769px -> 1442px - tablet landscape and laptop
 lg: 1443px -> 1920px - large screens
```

Comment: Could you explain why you need to override the break-points?

Comment: This is the requirement of the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to override `$grid-breakpoints` and `$container-max-widths`. Write these codes before where you import bootstrap.

#### Grid break-points

```css
// Define the minimum dimensions at which your layout will change,
// adapting to different screen sizes, for use in media queries.

$grid-breakpoints: (
        sm: 0,
        md: 769px,
        lg: 1443px,
) !default;
```

#### Grid containers

```css
// Define the maximum width of `.container` for different screen sizes.

$container-max-widths: (
        sm: 768px,
        md: 1442px,
        lg: 1920px,
) !default;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just import your variables before bootstrap import, because those variables are define with !default flag, so when your scss will be transforming to css it will use your override values.

```
$grid-breakpoints: (
  xs: 0,
  sm: 0,
  md: 769px,
  lg: 1443px,
  xl: 1921px
);

$container-max-widths: (
  sm: 540px,
  md: 720px,
  lg: 960px,
  xl: 1140px
) !default;

@import 'bootstrap'
```

Comment: And how should I modify the values in $container-max-width?

Comment: Under 769px the application is not responsive. Do you know why?

Comment: Also, if xs=0 and sm=0 then the build fails with this message: Invalid null operation: "null sub 0.02px"